# Attributes table doesn't transfer from external WMS to GeoServer WMS

Tags: geoserver, wms

I'm new to GeoServer and pretty much everything in this domain. I'm trying to load up Mining Tenement WMS data from an External WMS Source (https://services.slip.wa.gov.au/public/services/SLIP_Public_Services/Industry_and_Mining/MapServer/WMSServer) to my geoserver. Once loaded onto the server, I preview the layer but discover that the map does not have any attribute tables when I click on a tenement.

Please let me know where i'm going wrong and if you need any more information about this problem

Since my knowledge about this is limited and the case seems to not be covered by tutorials online, i dont know what to try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/cascaded/wms.html#features):

> WMS GetFeatureInfo requests will be passed to the remote WMS. If the remote WMS supports the `application/vnd.ogc.gml` format the request will be successful.

Unfortunately your server only provides information in:

```
 <GetFeatureInfo>
   <Format>application/vnd.esri.wms_raw_xml</Format>
   <Format>application/vnd.esri.wms_featureinfo_xml</Format>
   <Format>application/vnd.ogc.wms_xml</Format>
   <Format>application/geojson</Format>
   <Format>text/xml</Format>
   <Format>text/html</Format>
   <Format>text/plain</Format>
```